# Xamarin UI Test supports windows mobile app?

Tags: xamarin, windows-mobile

Evaluating the automation tools to automate Windows OS, Android OS, iOS mobile apps. Many tools are supporting Android OS and iOS.

XamarinUI Test supports Android & iOS. But I couldn't get information for Windows mobile app support. anybody tried for Windows mobile apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Xamarin's [Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/intro-to-uitest/#Requirements)

> Xamarin.UITest requires NUnit 2.6.3 or higher. Xamarin.UITest is not compatible with NUnit 3.0.
>
> Only Android and iOS applications are supported. It is not possible to
>   test Windows Phone applications.